# How to avoid Expect msg with HTTP 2.0.0 in elm?

Tags: elm

In elm's `Http 1.0.0` package, I could send a custom request like:

```
post : Endoint -> List (Http.Header) -> Http.Body -> Decoder a -> Http.Request a
post url headers body decoder =
    Http.request
        { method = "POST"
        , headers = headers
        , url = url
        , body = body
        , expect = Http.expectJson decoder
        , timeout = Nothing
        , withCredentials = False
        }
```

With the `post` function I wrote above, I can simply call it with, say, a `Decoder String`, and after the Http request sends, the response string will be decoded and returned. period. No need to create a `Msg` like:

```
type Msg
    = GotText (Result Http.Error String)
```

And no need to write a branch in `update` to handle this `Msg`.

However, as of `Http 2.0.0`, the `expect` argument is of type `Expect msg`, not `Expect a`, meaning that writing the `Msg` variation and additional branch to update will now be *required*.

I am writing an `Api.elm` file which makes Http requests. However, this means that now it will have to have its own `Msg` type and `update` function to run after these requests respond.

I used to think that `Home.elm` should only respond to messages from `Home.Msg` and `Home.update` not `Api.Msg` and `Api.update`. Am I wrong? Should `Api.elm` have its own `Msg` type and `update` function that changes other pages? Or would there be a better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just pass an `a -> msg` function to your `Api` functions?

Comment: That's exactly what I have been doing so far, but now I am working on authentication. As such, `Api.elm` defines an opaque `Token` type. To return this type to `Signup.elm`, it has to make two Http requests, and I don't know how to without using `Api.Msg` and `Api.update`. @glennsl

Comment: Actually, you're right. I could just handle all the update logic on the calling module's side and this doesn't affect `Token`s opacity. Thank you! @glennsl

Comment: @glennsl, if this question is answered, can you add it below? Otherwise people (like me) will come here trying to answer it :-)

Comment: I too am facing the same issue.  I don't understand the solution though.  Can someone provide a detailed response/example of what is required to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify what I was explaining in my question:

A custom request in Elm's HTTP 2.0.0 package looks like this:

```
request : 
  { method : String
  , headers : List Header
  , url = String
  , body = Body
  , expect = Expect msg
  , timeout = Maybe Float
  , withCredentials = Maybe String
  }
  -> Cmd msg
```

Wheras in Http 1.0.0 it looked like this:

```
request :
  { method : String
  , headers : List Header
  , url : String
  , body : Body
  , expect : Expect a
  , timeout : Maybe Float
  , withCredentials : Bool
  }
  -> Request a
```

The difference is that using the custom request from HTTP 2.0.0, I *needed* to pass-in a `Msg` to use this request.

Now, my problem was: I was using an `Api.elm` file. Every time I needed to issue an HTTP request, I would call `Api.request arg1 arg2...` from, say, `Login.elm`.

Since the `request` function in `Api.elm` demanded a `Msg` type, for, in this case, a login request I thought I would have to define a `Msg` of `GotLogin` within `Api.elm` and then handle how `GotLogin` would update `Login.elm` by writing an `update` branch for `GotLogin` within `Api.elm`.

However, I could just define a `GotLogin` `Msg` in `Login.elm` and pass that into `Api.request`. Since I've defined `GotLogin` in `Login.elm`, I would put a `GotLogin` branch in the update function of `Login.elm`, instead of `Api.elm`.

This also applies for any other request type from any other page (`Signup.elm`, `Home.elm`,...), meaning that `Api.elm`, should not have its own `update` function that updates other pages.

The whole point of `Login.elm` having its own `update` function, is that it should only be affected by the branches of its own `update` function, not ones from `Api.elm`.